# No reconoce using Rotativa en asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Acabo de instalar rotativa en mi proyecto, al instalar me genera la respectiva carpeta y todo, pero al momento de usar en namespace de rotativa no lo reconoce, al buscar en las referencias no esta, pero si me genera la carpeta respectiva de Rotativa con los archivos.

No se por que me pasa este error, alguien sabe el porque??

Esta es la Carpeta de rotativa al instalar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estas son todas las referencias que cuenta el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar con esto.

Comment: que componente de asp.net mvc es esa "Rotativa" que haces referencia ? en las imagenes que has puesto no veo ese componente y la carpeta no aplica a un proyecto web, solo hay .txt y .exe, eso no es web

Comment: al generador de pdf rotativa, al momento de instalar genera esa carpeta, pero no realiza la instalación en las referencias del proyecto

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta añadiendo la versión de .net que usas

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la versiones del paquete `nuget` para ver sus dependencias. Según la documentación, la versión `1.7.4.-rc`, le han hecho un downgrade para compatibilidad con 4.5. [Rotativa/1.7.4-rc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/1.7.4-rc)

Answer (score 1):

no se si sea tarde para responder, pero casualmente en esta ultima semana me ha tocado trabajar con esta librería y he logrado hacerla funcionar después de muchas pruebas e intentos. dejo mi código y comento mi experiencia para quien le pueda servir.

1. Trabajo con la versión .NET Framework 4.5.2
2. Versión Rotativa 1.6.3 (Debo mencionar q' probé todas las versiones hasta la 1.7.3 q es la actual, mas esta actual pide tener una versión de .NET mas actualizada)
3. Tuve problemas con el código JavaScript, leyendo por aquí y por allá debes tener en cuenta el código JavaScript (Mi código lo pase a JS Vanilla, cero JQuery, pues esa fue parte de mi solución, no estoy diciendo q así debe ser), este link me ayudo a q' me funcionara [the-features-of-using-rotativa-to-generate-pdf](https://www.smartspate.com/the-features-of-using-rotativa-to-generate-pdf/).
4. El 90% del código dinámico lo trabaje con razor en vez de consultas Ajax con JavaScript, para mas compatibilidad.
5. El JS lo coloque en la cabecera, esto fue recomendado en el link q te deje mas arriba.

JavaScript solo lo utilice para agregar un HTML dentro de un DIV, y a pesar de parecer algo sencillo, me formo mucho problema utilizar para q' me funcionara el actuar con JS.

Ahora si les comparto mi código para quien lo necesitare.

***JAVASCRIPT*** Quien llama al controlador

```
window.open(rutaAplicacion + "Solicitudes/imprimirContrato/" + vf_sol_id, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=" + screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height);
```

***CONTROLADOR***

```
public ActionResult imprimirContrato()
{
    string footer = "--footer-right \"Date: [date] [time]\" " + "--footer-center \"Page: [page] of [toPage]\" --footer-line --footer-font-size \"9\" --footer-spacing 5 --footer-font-name \"calibri light\"";
    //Donde dice new id = ... lo q hago es recibir el ID q envio por JS 
    return new ActionAsPdf("vercontrato", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]) })
    {
        IsJavaScriptDisabled = false,
        FileName = "contrato.pdf",
        PageMargins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
        CustomSwitches = footer
    };
}

public ActionResult vercontrato(int id)
{
            ViewBag.id = id;
            return View();
}
```

***VIEW con Razor***

```
@{ Layout = null;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Contrato</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ContratoPdf() {
      document.getElementById('pnl_contenidoId').innerHTML = document.getElementById('contrato').value;
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body >
  @{
      <!--Aqui consulto a la BD lo q necesito-->
      int vf_sol_id = Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.id);
      EntitisJuridica.solicitude sol = BusinessJuridica.solicitude.Buscar(vf_sol_id);
      EntitisJuridica.contrato con = BusinessJuridica.contrato.RetornaContratoSolicitud(vf_sol_id);
  }

  @*@{string contenido = @BusinessJuridica.contrato.Buscar(@con.con_id).con_contenido;}*@
  <input type="hidden" name="contrato" id="contrato" value="@BusinessJuridica.contrato.Buscar(@con.con_id).con_contenido" />
  <div class="conten-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="@sol.empresa.emp_imagen" style="width:200px; border:none; margin: 20px" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">

        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align:right; margin-top: -35px" class="token"><strong>TOKEN:</strong> @BusinessJuridica.contrato.GeneraTokenContrato(@con.con_id)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding:60px">
      <div class="pnl_contenido" id="pnl_contenidoId">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y compañeros de esta forma me funciono perfectamente, todo lo q necesite.

Espero a alguien le pueda servir.

Answer (score 0):

Editaré esta respuesta conforme tenga más datos, al usar el siguiente código (adáptalo a tu escenario):

```
public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF()
{
    //Aqui debes llamar a algún modelo que tú tengas.
    var model = new GeneratePDFModel();
    //Code to get content
    return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"}
}
```

¿Qué sucede? ¿Te lanza error?

Comment: Como dije, al instalar el paquete de rotativa me genera la carpeta pero no me reconoce el using Rotativa; y en las referencias no me aparece la referencia de rotativa, al probar el codigo me lanza error en Rotativa, dice que el que no se encuentra una referencia de ensamblado

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega la definición de tu proyecto :)

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema es la referencia a un componente una instalacion que crea una carpeta no es garantia de agregar la referencia al proyecto de desarrollo

Deberias agregala tu mismo en el proyecto, ayudandote con `nuget`

[Rotativa nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[ASP.NET MVC5 - Rotativa - Easy Way To Create PDF And Image Files](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-rotativa-easy-way-to-create-pdf-and-image-files/)

Comment: Si yo lo hago de esa forma, la cuestión que acabo de ver es la siguiente, estoy trabajando sobre .net 4.5 ya que es la version que corre el servidor de producción, y he creado un proyecto sobre .net 4.6.1 y si instalo de forma correcta

Comment: de casualidad sabrás cual es la versión de rotativa que corra de forma correcta sobre .net 4.5

Comment: Revisa la versiones del paquete nuget para ver sus dependencias. Según la documentación, la versión 1.7.4.-rc, le han hecho un downgrade para compatibilidad con 4.5. [Rotativa/1.7.4-rc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/1.7.4-rc)

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra creo que esa debería ser la respuesta a la pregunta

Comment: Gracias @JuanSalvadorPortugal, publicada respuesta

Comment: @JhonnyLuis pero es solo cuestion de leer un poco las versiones publicadas en nuget, si revisas el link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/1.7.4-rc , alli mismo lo dice en `Release Notes`: `Downgraded .Net FW to 4.5 for compatibility`